# Format datetime in subdataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have data `df`:

```
          Id    timestamp               data        Date
27585   27826   2020-01-02 08:55:46.297 19.0    2020-01-02
27586   27827   2020-01-02 08:55:46.397 20.0    2020-01-02
27587   27828   2020-01-02 08:55:47.283 20.0    2020-01-02
27588   27829   2020-01-02 08:55:47.383 21.5    2020-01-02
27589   27830   2020-01-02 08:55:48.287 21.5    2020-01-02
```

I would like to find the average `data` between `12pm` and `4pm` for each unique `Date`.

I tried:

```
for date in df['Date'].unique():                            
    df_date = df[df['Date'] == date]

    start_date = pd.to_datetime('12:00:00')
    end_date = pd.to_datetime('16:00:00')
    df_date1 = df_date.loc[(df_date['timestamp'].dt.time >= start_date) & 
                           (df_date['timestamp'].dt.time <= end_date)]

    df.set_index(["data"], inplace=True)
    df = df.sort_index()       
    df = df.resample('1S').fillna('ffill')
    df['data'].mean()
```

How can I format the `datetime` objects to filter the sub datasets time to `12pm` and `4pm` for each unique `Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) working with `DatetimeIndex` for select rows between 2 times and then aggregate `mean`:

```
#changed data sample for match
print (df)
          Id                timestamp  data        Date
27585  27826  2020-01-02 11:55:46.297  19.0  2020-01-02
27586  27827  2020-01-02 12:55:46.397  25.0  2020-02-02
27587  27828  2020-01-02 13:55:47.283  20.0  2020-02-02
27588  27829  2020-01-02 14:55:47.383  21.5  2020-03-02
27589  27830  2020-01-02 08:55:48.287  21.5  2020-04-02

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

print (df.set_index('timestamp')
       .between_time('12:00:00','16:00:00'))
                            Id  data        Date
timestamp                                       
2020-01-02 12:55:46.397  27827  25.0  2020-02-02
2020-01-02 13:55:47.283  27828  20.0  2020-02-02
2020-01-02 14:55:47.383  27829  21.5  2020-03-02

df1 = (df.set_index('timestamp')
       .between_time('12:00:00','16:00:00')
       .groupby('Date')['data']
       .mean())
print (df1)
Date
2020-02-02    22.5
2020-03-02    21.5
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

If need `resample` with `groupby` by `timestamp`s:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('timestamp')
       .between_time('12:00:00','16:00:00')
       .groupby('Date')['data']
       .resample('1S')
       .ffill())
print (df1)
Date        timestamp          
2020-02-02  2020-01-02 12:55:46     NaN
            2020-01-02 12:55:47    25.0
            2020-01-02 12:55:48    25.0
            2020-01-02 12:55:49    25.0
            2020-01-02 12:55:50    25.0
                                   ... 
            2020-01-02 13:55:44    25.0
            2020-01-02 13:55:45    25.0
            2020-01-02 13:55:46    25.0
            2020-01-02 13:55:47    25.0
2020-03-02  2020-01-02 14:55:47     NaN
Name: data, Length: 3603, dtype: float64
```

And then is possible count `mean` per first date level:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('timestamp')
       .between_time('12:00:00','16:00:00')
       .groupby('Date')['data']
       .resample('1S')
       .ffill()
       .mean(level=0)
       .reset_index())
print (df1)
         Date  data
0  2020-02-02  25.0
1  2020-03-02   NaN
```

Comment: Can I add another step to resample the `data` using `ffill`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Sure ;)

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Changed data sample. But not sure with mean. Do you need resample `timestamp` per groups by seconds?

Comment: Yes, if that's possible. I wanted to do 1)group by `Date`; 2)filter `timestamp` from `12pm` to `4pm` for each unique `Date`; 3)forward fill resample with 1 second frequency; 4)calculate the mean for `data` for each `Date`. Is it possible to do everything without for loop?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Ya, my solution working with swapped first and second step (I think here not problem) and then added another steps. Can you test with real data?

Comment: Yep working:) Thank you for the succinct code, as always.

Comment: I found that some rows are `NaN`, is there a way to replace them with the last row `data` value in each subset grouped by `Date`? I tried `df.loc[df.groupby('Date').date.idxmax()]` but it  returned `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Use `df.loc[df.groupby('Date')['date'].idxmax()]` - because `date` is column